# Difficulty understanding trigonometric functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, calculator

I have taken several calculus classes as part of highschool and general science degrees. Sin, cos, tan, and their inverse functions have always been this 'black box' to me that I never understood... instead I just memorized the operations and got through the classes that way.

[image]

My current understanding is that they are functions that 'map' an angle in a right-angle triangle to the ratio of two given sides (sin being opposite+hypoteneuse, and so forth).

So in this example that I have drawn, we have  a triangle with dimensions [4, 7, 8.06]. If you want to find theta, you just take the inverse cosine of ADJACENT (4) and HYPOTENEUSE (8.06). Since cosine is relating the RATIO of these two sides to the FOCUS ANGLE, it maps 0.4962 (the ratio) to 60 degrees.

My question is... how does my calculator DO that math? Is sine/cos really a complex polynomial function that is 'black boxed' to sine, cos, tan, etc. for simplicity's sake? How does it turn 0.4962 into 60?

Thank you for any insight, this idea bothers me a lot!

Comment: Also, your calculater finds the values using the Taylor Series Expansions of the functions, which is essentially that it just plugs values into a formula. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most calculators will use an approximation method - for example, a truncated Taylor series - which has error small enough that it will be well below what will appear on the display. I am not sure what specific implementation any calculator uses, though I assume it is not as simple as a Taylor polynomial (since those grow without bounds towards infinity).

Comment: Okay, perfect! Why do they not teach us this? I imagine initially, the functions were mapped by just calculating a bunch of discrete values, and then using Taylor polynomials to approximate the function, yes? So 'cos' and 'sin' aren't some magical process, its a polynomial that is approximating the relationship of angles to triangle sides... is that right?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I think modern calculators might use more sophisticated approximations. There are a few ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524424/can-i-approximate-sine-and-cosine-without-derivatives
This page: https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/sine_calculator.php claims the CORDIC algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) is used instead.

Comment: @Vranvs As a side note, which country are you from? This along with the unit circle definition seems to be a very standard topic in most high schools around the world. And it is inaccurate to describe trigonometric functions as polynomials, because the Taylor expansions are not 'polynomials'.

Comment: I am in Canada -- yes sorry, my math isn't super strong. But the fundamental confusion was 'what is the operation of taking the sine'. I had always just allow my calculator to magically transform the number. Now I see it is 'approximated' with another function.

Comment: @NamanKumar, I often refer to truncated Taylor series, which we were discussing, as Taylor polynomials, seeing as they are polynomial functions.
I only had this come up during undergrad classes, however.

Comment: @Vranvs Ah, don't worry- I just assumed that perhaps in your country these topics aren't even taught. I guess you probably didn't study math as a subject in high school or something.